# Where to catch exception?

Tags: powershell, try-catch

I have something along the lines of

C:\Scripts\Lib\Web\web.ps1

C:\Scripts\Tasks\Task1\task1.ps1

where task1.ps1 looks something like

```
. .\Lib\Web\web.ps1

Load-Url "http://server" "username" "password"
```

and web.ps1 looks something like

```
function Load-URL([string] $url, [string] $username, [string] $password)
{
  $pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
  $cred = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $pwd)

  $result = irm $url -cred $cred    
  return $result
}
```

Would any **try**/**catch** for exceptions which may fall out from the **irm** call be a concern of the Load-URL function or of the caller task1.ps1? I have it as a concern of the caller so that it can decide what an exception means in it's context. It may want to log or to do something completely different. Is there any contrary view to this?

Answer (score 0):

`Load-Url` presumably has a better understanding of how to deal with certain exceptions that would be thrown by `Invoke-RestMethod`. If `Load-Url` can deal with some of those in a way that adds value, then you should `try/catch` in `Load-Url`, and handle *those specific exceptions*.

Sometimes, the same exception class is thrown for a multitude of situations, and you must inspect the exception object in the `catch` block. If that is the case, and you don't want to handle some of those exceptions, then you can re-`throw` the exception:

```powershell
try {
    Invoke-RestMethod #arguments
} catch [Some.Generic.Net.Exception] {
    if ($_.Message -like '*Authentication*') {
        # Fix the issue here
    } else {
        throw $_
    }
}
```

Then, when the caller wraps its call of `Load-Url` in a try/catch, it will be able to catch any exceptions not handled by the function.